# Network communication with NSFileHandle & NSSocketPort

Tags: iphone, xcode, nssocketport

I need some scripts of Network communication with NSFileHandle & NSSocketPort
for Xcode programming...

Or, teach me how I can use NSSocketPort
in order to communicate with any socket-based program on pc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need [GCDAsyncSocket](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2010/11/introducing-gcd-based-asyncsocket.html), an excellent sockets library for iOS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, I'm beginning now to use XCODE, so it'll take a lot of time to apply this source....